# Mailer class and send files attach

Tags: php, mailer

I have input file multiple for send attach files using class php mailer , my code :

**PHP**

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['c_pics']); $i++) 
    {

    echo $_FILES['c_pics']['name'][$i] ;

    if($_FILES['c_pics']['name'][$i] != "") { continue; } 

    $name=$_FILES['c_pics']['name'][$i];
    $path=$_FILES['c_pics']['tmp_name'][$i]; 

    $mail->AddAttachment($path,$name);

}
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='file' name='c_pics[]' onchange="document.getElementById('upload_value').value=this.value" id='upload' multiple>
</form>
```

The problem is that it never receives the files , I don't know what the problem is because I have tried many times with the same result

Comment: Are you sure the file is being uploaded?  What does `$_FILES['c_pics']['name'][$i]` echo?  Why are you doing `onchange="document.getElementById('upload_value').value=this.value"`?

Comment: Onchange it´s for show the value in other field no problem with this because no show the normal file input css

Answer (score 1):

Try changing things like

```
$_FILES['c_pics']['name'][$i] ;
```

to

```
$_FILES['c_pics'][$i]['name'];
```

(Just moving the iterator before the key name)

as `$_FILES['c_pics']` is an array. `$_FILES['c_pics']['name']` will probably be undefined.

Comment: What is your error log saying? because I can guarantee that `$_FILES['c_pics']['name'][$i]` won't work